# Cloning environment in elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am wanting to update my Rails EB Linux to 2.12.2 from 1.11.8, so I cloned the environment and committed to it but I am getting this error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "example.ccexample.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (111.11.21.22) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Another error -- likely the same issue?:**

```
/opt/elastticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh failed.
```

My env variables are all correct so shouldn't the database just simply connect?

This is the error log:

```
    [2020-12-31T22:05:28.834Z] INFO  [5012]  - [Application update app-example/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_db_migration.sh] : Starting activity...
[2020-12-31T22:07:45.564Z] INFO  [5012]  - [Application update example/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_db_migration.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir
  + EB_SCRIPT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir
  + EB_SUPPORT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
  + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars-wrapper.sh
  +++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir
  ++ EB_SUPPORT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
  ++ set +x
  + RAKE_TASK=db:migrate
  + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/use-app-ruby.sh
  ++ . /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
  +++ CHRUBY_VERSION=0.3.9
  +++ RUBIES=()
  +++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
  +++ [[ -d /opt/rubies ]]
  ++++ ls -A /opt/rubies
  +++ [[ -n ruby-2.4.10
  ruby-2.5.8
  ruby-2.6.6
  ruby-current ]]
  +++ RUBIES+=("$dir"/*)
  +++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
  +++ [[ -d /.rubies ]]
  +++ unset dir
  +++ cat /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.ruby_version
  ++ chruby 2.5.8
  ++ case "$1" in
  ++ local dir match
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.10
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ match=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.6
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-current
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ [[ -z /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8 ]]
  ++ shift
  ++ chruby_use /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8 ''
  ++ [[ ! -x /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/ruby ]]
  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
  ++ export RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8
  ++ RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8
  ++ export RUBYOPT=
  ++ RUBYOPT=
  ++ export PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  ++ PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  +++ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/ruby -
  ++ eval 'export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby;
  export RUBY_VERSION=2.5.8;
  export GEM_ROOT="/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0";'
  +++ export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ export RUBY_VERSION=2.5.8
  +++ RUBY_VERSION=2.5.8
  +++ export GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  +++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  ++ ((  0 != 0  ))
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb db:migrate' webapp
```

I also updated the config.yml with the new environment names:

branch-defaults:
master:
environment: NewName
environment-defaults:
NewName:
branch: null
repository: null
RevoltVendor-env:
branch: null
repository: null
global:
application_name: App Name
default_ec2_keyname: null
default_platform: Puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux
default_region: us-east-1
include_git_submodules: true
instance_profile: null
platform_name: null
platform_version: null
profile: eb-cli
sc: git
workspace_type: Application

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are security group rules on the RDS?

Comment: I have 1 security group.  I click on "VPC security groups", click on "Security Group ID", Then Edit Inbound Rules, but now when I try to add the cloned env, it doesn't pop up.  Is there something else?

Comment: What are these inbound rules?

Comment: I have 2 rules, both are for All Traffic, Protocol and Port range is All for both.  1 is for a default security group with desc "default VPC security group", the other is for another one with a description "SecurityGroup for ElasticBeanstalk environment".

Comment: I just added another one that i saw with the desc "SecurityGroup for ElasticBeanstalk environment" and the app now loads.  I assume this was created on the clone?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Cloning did create new SG. If you don't mine I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **wrong security group** (SG) inbound rules in RDS. The EB cloning operation creating new SG, which was not reflected in the SG of the RDS.

The **solution** was to update the SG of the RDS and add the SG associated with the cloned EB environment.